# how to get sql server or database name from a VB2010 user entered textbox?

Tags: sql, sql-server, vba

I'm trying to get information from user. i have an application that asks the user for the server and database they need to connect to. Using just the server and database name in the code works but i need the user the enter the information and be able to connect to the server they entered. here is the code i have

connectionString = "Server=servername; Database=databasename;Trusted_Connection=True"
the above line connects without a problem, but below gives me an error that the user cannot connect

connectionString = "Server=txtServer.Text; Database=txtDatabase.Text;Trusted_Connection=True"
this does not connect to server, any ideas? should i use concatenate tried efforts fails.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first line you wrote :

`connectionString = "Server=servername;Database=databasename;Trusted_Connection=True"`

**sets** `connectionString`

**to** `Server=servername; Database=databasename; Trusted_Connection=True`

Whereas the second line you wrote :

`connectionString = "Server=txtServer.Text;Database=txtDatabase.Text;Trusted_Connection=True"`

**sets** `connectionString`

**to** `txtServer.Text; Database=txtDatabase.Text;Trusted_Connection=True`

What you need to do is :

1. Take the variables out of the string
2. Concatenate them into the string using &

The following code should work, assuming the variables are well set and contain the correct data.

`connectionString = "Server=" & txtServer.Text & "; Database=" & txtDatabase.Text & "; Trusted_Connection=True"`

Answer (score 0):

You are not adding the values that your text boxes contain instead you are adding the literal `testbox name .Text` as your properties. You need to do the following to get the actual values from the text boxes.

```
connectionString = "Server=" + txtServer.Text + "; database= "+txtDatabase.Text +";Trusted_Connection=True"
```

**Edit**

Because we are concatenating strings you are better of using the `&` operator instead of the `+` to avoid invalid cast errors

```
connectionString = "Server=" & txtServer.Text & "; database= " & txtDatabase.Text & ";Trusted_Connection=True"
```

Comment: Oh damn! Never realized "+" worked to concatenate strings! Thanks!!